# Finding a first letter most repeated in an string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Good evening, I proceed to explain my situation. I started to get interested in javascript which started to dabble
 in this language, I have been doing some online courses which I have encountered the following task, basically I am trying through the condition "for" tell me what is the first repeated letter of a string also adding the funsion ".UpperCase () "which at the beginning worked best, until I entered more characters to the string in this case" x "throwing me as output result" undefined "instead of" the most repeated word is: X "reach the case that the string should Consider all the letters regardless of whether they are lowercase or capital letters, for which I ask for help to understand if ¿there is another way? for this task and thus move forward (Sorry for my bad english)

Well i making this task in JavasScript with Atom Editor

```js
var word = "SQSQSQSSaaaassssxxxY";
var contendor = [];
var calc = [];
var mycalc = 0;

function repeat() {
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (contendor.includes(word[i])) {} else {
      contendor.push(word[i])
      calc.push(0)
    }
  }
  for (var p = 0; p < word.length; p++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < contendor.length; l++) {
      if (word[p].toUpperCase() == word[l]) {
        calc[l] = calc[l] + 1
      }
    }
  }
  for (var f = 0; f < calc.length; f++) {
    if (calc[f] > mycalc) {
      mycalc = calc[f]
    }
  }
}
repeat()

console.log("The first letter repeated its: " + contendor[mycalc])
```

I expected the output of the String to be: "X"

but the actual output is: "Undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error in your script is that you store the wrong value in `mycalc`:

```
  mycalc = calc[f]
```

Since you want `mycalc` to be an *index*, the above should have been

```
  mycalc = f
```

Now, you will get a result, but your code is actually going through a lot of effort to find the *uppercase* character that is repeated *most often*, not *first*.

Your comparison should have used `toUpperCase` on both sides of the comparison, otherwise lower case letters will never match.

To get the character that was repeated *most often*, you could use a `Map` (to keep track of the counts like you did in `calc`):

```js
function mostRepeated(str) {
    const map = new Map;
    let result;
    let maxCount = 0;
    for (let ch of str) {
        ch = ch.toUpperCase();
        let count = (map.get(ch) || 0) + 1;
        map.set(ch, count);
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            result = ch;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var word = "MBXAYMZAXmZYxxxxxxxxxxmBxAYMZaXmZY";
console.log(mostRepeated(word));
```

Note that you should better use function parameters and local variables. Declaring your variables as global is not considered best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i need to learn more of the functions and parameters and the use of "map" its very interesting i try to take a look this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `index` of most repeated letter, you can use `Array.from` to convert the word into an array. Add a map function to make all letters uppercase.

Get the count of each letter by using `reduce` and `Object.entries`

Use `indexOf` to the get the index of the lettet in the array. Please note that `indexOf` count the letters from 0.

```js
var word = "MBXAYMZAXmZYxxxxxxxxxxmBxAYMZaXmZY";
var letters = Array.from(word, o => o.toUpperCase());
var [highestLetter, highestCount]= Object.entries(letters.reduce((c, v) => (c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1, c), {})).reduce((c, v) => c[1] > v[1] ? c : v);
var index = letters.indexOf(highestLetter);

console.log("Most repeated letter:", highestLetter);
console.log("Count:", highestCount);
console.log("First Index:", index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the letter that occurs the most number of times in a string by:

1. first creating a map that relates each unique letter, to the number of times it occurs in the string
2. converting that map to an array of "key/value" entries, and then sorting those entries by the "count value"
3. returning the "letter key" that has the largest count

One way to express this in JavaScript would be via the following:

```js
function findMaxLetter(word) {

  /* Create a map that relates letters to the number of times that letter occours */
  const letterCounts = Array.from(word).reduce((map, letter) => {
    
    return { ...map, [letter] : (map[letter] === undefined ? 0 : map[letter] + 1) }
    
  }, {})
  
  /* Sort letters by the number of times they occour, as determined in letterCounts map */
  const letters = Object.entries(letterCounts).sort(([letter0, count0], [letter1, count1]) => {
    
    return count1 - count0
    
  })
  .map(([letter]) => letter)
  
  /* Return letter that occoured the most number of times */
  return letters[0]
}

console.log("The first letter repeated its: " + findMaxLetter("MBXAYMZAXmZYxxxxxxxxxxmBxAYMZaXmZY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("The first letter repeated its: " + contendor[mycalc])`
You tried to print the 14th index of `contendor` which has only 9 values, that is why your log result was undefined.

You probably wanted to print `word[mycalc]`.

Also if you intended to count `x` as `X`, you should have added toUpperCase() to every letter you process/go-through.

This is only a note to the issues in your code, there are better/faster/cleaner solutions to reach the result which i am sure other answers will provide.

Answer (score 0):

I this is solution is most detailed for you

```
function func( word ){

    word = word.toLowerCase();

    var i, charCountCache = {};

    //store all char counts into an object
    for( i = 0; i < word.length; i++){

      if( charCountCache[ word[ i ] ] )
        charCountCache[ word[ i ] ] = charCountCache[ word[ i ] ] + 1;
      else
        charCountCache[ word[ i ] ] = 1;
    }

    //find the max value of char count in cached object
    var fieldNames = Object.keys( charCountCache )
    , fieldValues  = Object.values( charCountCache )
    , mostReapeatChar = '', mostReapeatCharCount = 0;


      for( i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++ ){

        if( mostReapeatCharCount < fieldValues[i] ){
          mostReapeatCharCount = fieldValues[i];
          mostReapeatChar = fieldNames[i];
        }

      }    

    console.log('most repeating char: ', mostReapeatChar, ' no of times: ', mostReapeatCharCount )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

my advice would be to create a hashmap such as 
`letter => [indexLetter1, indexLetter2].`

From that hashmap, you could easily find your first repeated letters.

For that string `MBXAYMZAXmZYxxxxxxxxxxmBxAYMZaXmZY`, hashmap will look like

```
[
    M => [0,5,..],
    B => [1, ..],
    X => [2, ..],
    ...
]
```

now you can find every letter with multiple values in its array, then in those arrays take the one with the lowest value.